# PlasticSCM: How to set up encryption when using Distributed mode

Tags: plasticscm

I'm new to Plastic, having joined an organisation that's using it. It's a small organisation and they've only used it in Centralised mode up till now.

I'm a developer with plenty of experience of git (and perforce FWIW), and I'm very keen to try out the Distributed way of working in Plastic.

The organisation's cloud server uses encryption, and they've provided the files (cryptedservers.conf and key file) to put into AppData/Local/plastic4, and that all seems to be working for me fine... in Centralised mode.

But I'm now a bit stuck in the process of trying to set up a local repo and sync to the cloud repo (I've been following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUqg0Rfrqfk )

I've created a local repository and set up a sync view, but when I try to "Pull visible" I'm getting the "Server Encryption" pop-up asking me to enter a password.

I was seeing this same pop-up in Centralised before I copied over the files mentioned above, and then it went away.

So how come now, when trying to pull to a local repo, I'm seeing it again? Is the problem actually with my local repo not being set up with encryption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that any sync operation is performed by your local server on your client machine, rather than your local client.

You will need to add the cryptedservers.conf and .key files to your server installation folder on your local machine (Default location: C:\Program Files\PlasticSCM5\server)

Please note: make sure that you are using an empty local repository for this, you do not want to be syncing partly encrypted data!